# IndexOutOfBoundsException when writing a list of players to a file

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm working on assignment for OOP and am stuck on the last step which is, "Write all players to an output file that has a similar format of the input file."

I need to know how to print all the info in the main to an output file with the same format as the input file and I use here ArrayList. it's working fine when I print the name and the height but when I want to print season or score, an exception appears.

```
pw.write(t1.getName() + "; " + t1.getCity() + "\n");
for (int m = 0; m < p2.size(); m++) {
    pw.print(t1.getPlayerList().get(m).getName() + "; " + t1.getPlayerList().get(m).getHeight() + "; ");
    pw.println(t1.getPlayerList().get(m).getSeasonalRecords().get(m).getScores());
}
```

it works well, but when I write

```
pw.println(t1.getPlayerList().get(m).getSeasonalRecords().get(m).getScores());
```

appear something is wrong
that the exceptions that I got

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)

Comment: What do you understand that exception to mean?

Comment: The arraylist is not as big as you expect it to be.

Comment: `p2.size()` returns a number that is bigger than `t1.getPlayerList().size()`. I guess you probably think that they are the same size but it appears that they are not. You need to debug your code and try to discover why the sizes are different. If you need help debugging your code then I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Note that you should **not** post all your code. Just post the minimal amount of code that causes the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue is described in the comments: index `m` exceeds the number of seasonal records and definitely it may take another nested loop to print the seasonal records.

It may be better to replace `for` loops with indexes with `for-each` to make the code shorter, more readable and less prone to the mentioned errors:

```java
for (var player : t1.getPlayerList()) {
    pw.println(player.getName() + "; " + player.getHeight() + "; ");

    for (var seasonRecord : player.getSeasonalRecords()) {
        pw.println(seasonalRecord.getScores());
    }
}
```